# Ajax, результат получить как массив

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Мне необходимо обратиться через ajax на сервер и ответ получить как массив. Вот код php:

```
$result = json_encode($xmlChange);
echo $result;
```

Вид ответа:

```
{"transaction":[{"id":"0","btc":"0.2","dtime":"25"},{"id":"1","btc":"0.2","dtime":"25"}]}
```

Вот ajax функция:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:'index.php',
    success:function(msg){
        var result = JSON.parse(msg);
        $('.result').html(result);
    }
  });
```

В ответ ничего

Comment: Так а что идёт в ответ, что будет в `msg`?

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов сейчас там ничего нет, мне надо массив

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов я потом етот массив уже распихаю по тегам

Comment: То есть сейчас, в самой переменной `msg` ничего нет? Она пуста?

Comment: В консоль браузера заглядывали? Вы распарсили ответ в объект и пытаетесь его затолкать в строчный параметр jQuery функции `.html()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:'index.php',
    success:function(msg){
        //var result = JSON.parse(msg);
        console.log(typeof msg, msg);
    },
    error: function(request) {
        console.log("ERROR", request);
    }
});
```

Сообщите, что в консоли браузера.

> string
>   {"transaction":[{"id":"0","btc":"0.2","dtime":"25"},{"id":"1","btc":"0.2","dtime":"25"}]}

В `success`-обработчик приходит строка (что странно, я считал, что jQuery в отсутствие `dataType` пытается определить тип данных ответа). После `JSON.parse` строка преобразуется в объект. 
Функция `$().html(...)` принимает html-строку или функцию. Когда туда подается js объект, `innerHTML` выбранных DOM-элементов очищается.

```
success:function(msg){
    var result = JSON.parse(msg);
    for (var i = 0; i < result.transaction.length; i++) {
      $('.result').append($("<div></div>").text(result.transaction[i].dtime));
    }
}
```

Вариант без `JSON.parse`:

```
dataType: "json",
success:function(result){
    for (var i = 0; i < result.transaction.length; i++) {
      $('.result').append($("<div></div>").text(result.transaction[i].dtime));
    }
}
```

Comment: `string {"transaction":[{"id":"0","btc":"0.2","dtime":"25"},{"id":"1","btc":"0.2","dtime":"25"}]}`

Comment: @Winteriscoming Господи да ты прочти комментарий от меня выше в вопросе, в `$('.result').html()` нужно передать строку, а ты функцией `var result = JSON.parse(msg);` распарсил данные в объект JS как ты собираешь объект затолкать в строковый параметр? попробуй сделать так - `$('.result').html(result.transaction[0].dtime)`

Comment: Когда я ручками делаю так `$('.result').html("123");` все ок

Comment: @RifmaMan Если все нормально, то он должен увидеть по крайней мере "[object Object]".

Comment: @RifmaMan спасибо, работает.

Comment: @Igor ничего он не увидет, это тебе не alert

Comment: @Winteriscoming нужно через `for` перебрать `result.transaction` и вывести что необходимо, я просто не понимаю по ответу что именно нужно выводить, опирайся на строку и всё ясно в принципе должно быть как дальше действовать

Comment: @RifmaMan да, Вы правы.

Comment: Чего-то я под конец дня спылил, Igor, поправь ответ пожалуйста и напиши как ему стоит работать с объектом который он распарсил.